# Adding chunks of array into array list in java

Tags: java, arrays

i want to break an array(with random integers values) into smaller chunks of equal size, and assign the elements based on the value of arrays based. example if i have an array of size 9, and want to divide it into 3 chunks, the numbers between 0 and 3 are assigned into the first chunk and numbers between 4-6 are assigned into the second and the rest into the third chunk.
I have to iterate over the separate chunks(can stay for now). finally add all the chunks into array list.

```
int[] originalarray = init[9];
     int number = original.length/numerToDivede;
Arraylist<int[]> bigarray = new Arraylist<>();
                int[] array1= null;
                int[] array2;
                int[] array3;

                for(int i=0;i<originalarrays.length-1;i++){
                    if(originalArrays[i] < numberTodivide){
                        // add to the first array1;
                    }else if (originalArrays[i] < 2*numberTodivide){
                      // add to the second array
                    }else
                   // add to the third array
```

this is the way i approached, but every thing is hard coded. con i do it dynamically? appreciate for helping!

Comment: Why not an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList` of `int`, so you don't have to care about the size of array?

Comment: I guess I'd need to know what the use case is here, but [`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-int:A-int-int-) can be used to copy part of an array to a new array.

Comment: @vishal-wadhwa more precisely an `ArrayList` of `Integer`s

Comment: is it `originalArrays[i] < numberTodivide` or `i < numberTodivide`?

Comment: @ vishal-wadhwa you are right , that way is even easier, but i want to bubble sort the chunks apart. i thought the memory allocation will be very bad.

Comment: @Powerlord, the problem with copy is that i want to bubble sort the chunks and then simply copy the bubble sorted, otherwise after i merged all the chunks, i have to sort them again

Comment: you r right i < numberToDivede

Comment: It seems like you want to implement a divide and conquer algorithm like merge sort. In such cases you're not supposed to create new arrays but implement your algorithm in such a way that you can treat the original array as the combination of subarrays in place. So instead of storing mutiple arrays you would be storing only the start and end index of all the subarrays and use them to operate in the original array in place.

Comment: that seems to be a good and more efficient approach, could you please share me if you have suck kind of code or link where i can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you

```
List<Integer> bigarray = new ArrayList<>();
bigarray.addAll(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,33,3,4,1,2,1));
List<List<Integer>> outputList = new ArrayList<>();

while(!bigarray.isEmpty()){
    List<Integer> tmpList = bigarray.stream()
    .filter(item -> item == bigarray.get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    //filter all item has been collect this time
    List<Integer> filter = bigarray.stream().filter(item -> item != bigarray.get(0)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    bigarray.clear();
    bigarray.addAll(filter);

    // add the result in this time
    outputList.add(tmpList);
}

outputList.forEach(list -> list.forEach(item -> System.out.print(item+", ")));
```

Comment: the outputList is the result list that contain all chunks you need